# Intersection of two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having the following array defined:

```
   array(
    'name'=>'Blue',
    'age'=>'0',
    'skin'=>array(
        'White Skin','Tanned Skin'
    ),
    'eye'=>array(
        'Black','Brown','Honey'
    ),
    'personality'=>array(
        'Intelligent','Warm','Trustworthy','Sweet'
    ),
    'ocassion'=>array(
        'Every day wear','Celebrations','Restaurant Dinner','Feasts','Visiting friends'
    ),
    'hair'=>'All Colors',
    'style'=>array(
        'Loved to be admired','Center of attention'
    ),
    'description'=>'Blue lens are perfect for any..'
);
```

and I am trying to find the number of matches, from an HTML form into this array. A possible return from the HTML form, in array format would be:

```
Array
(
[age] => 16
[skin] => Tanned Skin
[eye] => Brown
[personality] => Array
    (
        [0] => Intelligent
        [1] => Warm
        [2] => Trustworthy
    )

[ocassion] => Weddings
[hair] => Dark Brown
[style] => Array
    (
        [0] => Style Queen
        [1] => Testing val
    )

)
```

I have tried iterating trough each key of the first array, but failed to achieve what I want, and also I've tried using the function `array_intersect_assoc($stack,$search)` but it seems it won't find the exact matches because the $search array ( second example ) has some key=>value pairs that are of type string, and it cannot match any occurrence into the first array because the value is actually an array, and not a string.

Can someone point me an idea or can let me know what's best to do over here?

I have tried a lot of things in the last 3 hours but no success.

Comment: What **exactly** do you consider a match?

Comment: For example in the defined array I have ``'eye'=>array('Black','Brown','Honey')`` and from HTML I get ``[eye] => Brown`` . I consider that the response from HTML is being found into the defined array, so it's a match

Comment: Also, if I get an array from HTML like the **personality** or **style** I consider a match each value of that array that can be found into the defined array, under the _personality_ or _style_ array keys.

Comment: Ok, so what you need is an array consisting of values found in both arrays. I'm dumb. :D

Comment: Yes. But the values should match under each array key. So, for each array key got from the HMTML I need to count how many of the values (either only a string, either a sub array ) can be found in the defined array

Comment: Well, any reaction to my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so how about this.
The source data:

```
$demands = array(
    'name'=>'Blue',
    'age'=>'0',
    'skin'=>array(
        'White Skin','Tanned Skin'
    ),
    'eye'=>array(
        'Black','Brown','Honey'
    ),
    'personality'=>array(
        'Intelligent','Warm','Trustworthy','Sweet'
    ),
    'ocassion'=>array(
        'Every day wear','Celebrations','Restaurant Dinner','Feasts','Visiting friends'
    ),
    'hair'=>'All Colors',
    'style'=>array(
        'Loved to be admired','Center of attention'
    ),
    'description'=>'Blue lens are perfect for any..'
);

$possible_match = array(
    'age'=>'16',
    'skin'=>'Tanned Skin',
    'eye'=>'Brown',
    'personality'=>array(
        'Intelligent','Warm','Trustworthy'
    ),
    'ocassion'=>array(
        'Weddings'
    ),
    'hair'=>'Dark Brown',
    'style'=>array(
        'Style Queen','Testing value'
    )
);
```

And the match-making algorithm:

```
$result = array();
$count_matches = 0;

// Go through all the demands
foreach ($demands as $key => $value){

    // If there's a matching key in the possible match array
    if (isset($possible_match[$key])){
        // If there are more demanded values
        if (is_array($value)){
            // Let all demanded values be lowercase
            $value = array_map('strtolower', $value);
            // If there are more possible matching values
            if (is_array($possible_match[$key])){
                // Let all possibly matching values be lowercase, too
                $possible_match[$key] = array_map('strtolower', $possible_match[$key]);
                // And then do the intersect.
                $intersect = array_intersect($value, $possible_match[$key]);
                if ($intersect){
                    // If that intersect is not empty, add that to the resulting array
                    $result[$key] = $intersect;
                    $count_matches += count($intersect);
                };
            } else {
                // If there's only one possible matching value, search that
                // value in the demaned array
                if (in_array(strtolower($possible_match[$key]), $value, true)){
                    // And add it to the results
                    $result[$key][] = strtolower($possible_match[$key]);
                    $count_matches++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (is_array($possible_match[$key])){
                // If there are more possible matching values but the demand is a string,
                // find that string in those possible values
                $possible_match[$key] = array_map('strtolower', $possible_match[$key]);
                if (in_array(strtolower($value), $possible_match[$key], true)){
                    // And add it to the results
                    $result[$key] = $value;
                    $count_matches++;
                }
            } else {
                // If the demanded value is only one (= it's a string and not an array)
                // and the possible match is also a string, do a lowercase compare
                // + if there's a word "all" in the demanded value, pass it at all times ;D
                if (strtolower($possible_match[$key]) == strtolower($value)
                    || stripos($value, "all") !== false){
                    // And add it to the resulting array
                    $result[$key] = strtolower($value);
                    $count_matches++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

var_dump ($result);
var_dump ($count_matches);
```

There may be some opportunities for optimizing, but the basic idea should be there :)

The result:

```
array (size=4)
  'skin' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'tanned skin' (length=11)
  'eye' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'brown' (length=5)
  'personality' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'intelligent' (length=11)
      1 => string 'warm' (length=4)
      2 => string 'trustworthy' (length=11)
  'hair' => string 'all colors' (length=10)
```

Plus the count, if you'd like:

```
int 6
```

Comment: Thanks. It works exactly as it should. I have taken another approach finally with two foreach loops, but then I have seen your answer and I've found it more optimised. So I used yours. And sorry for the big delay.